# Out-of-core training of Scikit's LinearSVC Classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How do you train Scikit's [LinearSVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html) on a dataset too big or impractical to fit into memory? I'm trying to use it to classify documents, and I have a few thousand tagged example records, but when I try to load all this text into memory and train LinearSVC, it consumes over 65% of my memory and I'm forced to kill it before my system becomes totally unresponsive.

Is it possible to format my training data as a single file and feed it into LinearSVC with a filename instead of having to call the `fit()` method?

I found [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html) guide, but it only really covers classification, and assumes training is done incrementally, something LinearSVC doesn't support.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, non-incremental implementations like LinearSVC would need the entire data set to train on. Unless you create an incremental version of it, you might be unable to use LinearSVC.

There are classifiers in scikit-learn that can be used incrementally just like in the guide you found wherein it was using an SGDClassifier. The SGDClassifier has the *partial_fit* method which allows you to train it in batches. There are a couple of other classifiers that support incremental learning such as [SGDCLassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html), [Multinomial Naive Bayes](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html) and [Bernoulli Naive Bayes](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.html)

Comment: Compared to LinearSVC, SGDClassifier is much less accurate, but your conclusion is probably right.

Comment: @Cerin: `SGDClassifier` can be tweaked to implement the same model as `LinearSVC` by supplying the right parameters.

Comment: @larsmans, But finding those parameters can be very difficult. And depending on the size of the mini-batch, the resulting classification accuracy can vary wildly.

Comment: @Cerin: understandable. There has been talk on the scikit-learn mailing list about replacing Liblinear (used for `LinearSVC`) with something based on [lightning](https://github.com/mblondel/lightning). That might lead to a more scalable implementation. Don't hold your breath, though.

Comment: @larsmans, lightning looks like it has an identical API. How would it better handle out-of-core situations? Also, I just ran a test comparing LinearSVC to SGDClassifier, and on average I experienced a 30% drop in accuracy.

Comment: @Cerin I never experienced such a significant drop for sparse data with large nr of features (mostly NLP type of problems). Did you tune the regularization parameter - for sparse data the default learning rate heuristic works pretty good IMHO.

Comment: @Cerin more context needed: when you transform your data into a feature matrix what's the number of rows and columns? Is the matrix sparse or dense? Do all features mean the same (eg. word counts) or do they differ (block of dense features, block of binary, ...)?

Comment: @Cerin: I'm not sure if it could learn out-of-core, but it doesn't need to copy the entire dataset into its own format like Liblinear does.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Generator function like this.

```
def lineGenerator():
    with open(INPUT_FILENAMES_TITLE[0],'r') as f1:
        title_reader = csv.reader(f1)
        for line in title_reader:
            yield line[0]
```

Then you can call the Classifier as

```
clf = LinearSVC()
clf.fit(lineGenerator())
```

This assumes INPUT_FILENAMES_TITLE[0] is your filename.

Comment: `Fit()` still reads everything into memory before it starts the batch learning process, so using a generator wouldn't significantly change the overall performance. I think you're confusing this with `partial_fit()`, which would indeed work incrementally with a generator reading the data file line-by-line. Unfortunately, `LinearSVC` doesn't support `partial_fit()`.